# Why I always have to do export path=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin in the terminal before doing commands

Tags: terminal, path, zsh

I have installed node , homebrew etc, but as soon as I want to use them on my terminal or IDE, I get the error: zsh: command not found: npm or zsh: command not found ....

Nevertheless, as soon as I do export path=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin I have no more problems, could you please fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Read _man zsh_ , section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_. It shows which files a new zsh process is executing, and you put all zsh configuration into one of those, whichever suits you. A good place would often be `.zshrc`. BTW, I would **extend** the path instead of setting it in a hard way, i.e. `path+=(/opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin)`.

Comment: Aside from this, the way to set the path as you posted is **wrong** anyway. If you want to provide the searchpath as colon-separated string, the variable is named `PATH`, not `path`. If you want to provide the searchpath as array, the variable is named 'path`. Using the array is in general easier and I would recommend the latter.

Comment: Also, `PATH` is *already* exported unless your system configuration files are doing something *very* questionable. You almost never need to set `PATH` from scratch in your own configuration files,, instead *adding* directories to the current value.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded, it was going to modify the zshrc file via: nano ~/.zshrc
and add export path=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin and save :)